# Excel: how to deal with multiple "if" conditions in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know how to test one condition with =if.

But how can I test more than one condition in one cell.

```
Exemple:
if the number in a cell A1 = 0 we write null
else if the number is > 10 we write "number > 10"
else if the number is >15 and <20 we write "number >15 and <20"
```

Can anyone help please.
Thank you.

Comment: ... and what if it is more than 20?

Comment: In addition to the nested `If` statements, you can use a `Vlookup()` table, using non-exact matches. Let me know if you're interested in this...I'd say to use a `Vlookup()` instead if your `If` statements get to be more than say 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do exactly what you described with the nested IF function. However it doesn't take into account if the number is exactly 10.

```
=IF(A1=0,"Null",IF(AND(A1>15,A1<20),"number >15 and <20",IF(A1>10,"number > 10")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Write nested IF function calls. For example:

```
IF(A1=0, "null", 
    IF(A1 > 10, "number > 10", 
         IF(AND(A1 > 15, A1 < 20), "number >15 and <20", "something else")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a nested `IF` function:

```
=IF(A1=0,"null",IF(AND(A1>15,A1<20),"number >15 and <20",IF(A1>10,"number > 10", "n/a")))
```